# Ubuntu Eee / EasyPeasy - Offtopic?

Tags: discussion, scope

> EasyPeasy is 'Formerly known as Ubuntu Eee, a project optimized for netbooks.'

Is this really not the right place to ask questions about this Ubuntu distro? The UI says Ubuntu in the upper right corner. I just need some help getting YouTube to play, probably just an issue with the flash plugin which is being handled by VNC.

Comment: Not only is not an official Ubuntu distro, it's also long dead.

Answer (score 12):

Ubuntu Eee sounds a lot like the long since dead netbook remix project.

Whether this is the case or not, the Ubuntu Eee operating system is no longer an official Ubuntu distro.

[Per the help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), we only support official Ubuntu derivatives (server, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, etc - this is not an all inclusive list) here on Ask Ubuntu.

Your question sounds like it would fit over on [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com), though.